# pst-optic: draw lens and object without rays

Tags: pst-optic

I am using latex with pst-optic for my classes. For my exercises, I would like to draw a lens with the focal point, the object, but without the rays and the image. In this way, the students can construct the image by tracing the rays directly on the hand-out I produce with latex/pst. 
I could then later give the solution with the rays.
Is there a way to do that easily, with a simple switch or argument?

With the `drawing=false`argument, only the lens is drawn, with no axis and no object! I then have to add manually the latters, axis, object...

An example: This is what pst-optics produces, with the all the rays and the image:

[image]

Here is what I would like to have, the axis, the lens, and the object (notice all I have to add that pst-optic could do easily...):
[image]

Here is the code to produce the two pictures:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-optic}

\begin{document}

% Example using pst-optics:
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-15.5,-6)(15,6)
\rput(0,0){\lens[lensType=CVG,yBottom=-3.5,yTop=3.5,lensGlass=false,lensHeight=6.5,
spotFi=315,lensWidth=0.05,lensColor=black,
focus=2.0,OA=-4,AB=2,spotAi=10,spotBi=270,spotFi=90] } 
\end{pspicture}

% the same, without the rays, but I have to draw many things myself:
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=false](-5,-3.5)(5,3.5) 
\pnode(2,-2){FF}
\qdisk(-2,0){1.5pt} \rput(-2,-0.5){F}
\qdisk(2,0){1.5pt} \rput(2,-0.5){F}
\rput(0,0){\lens[lensType=CVG,yBottom=-3.5,yTop=3.5,lensGlass=false,lensHeight=6.5,drawing=false,
spotFi=315,lensWidth=0.05,lensColor=black] 
\psline[linewidth=1pt](xLeft)(xRight) 
}
\psline[length=2,linewidth=2pt,arrows=->](-4,0)(-4,2)
\rput(-4,-0.5){A}
\rput(-4,2.5){B}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\rput(0,0){\lens[lensType=CVG,yBottom=-3.5,yTop=3.5,lensGlass=false,lensHeight=6.5,
    spotFi=315,lensWidth=0.05,lensColor=black,rayColor=white,% <<<<========
    focus=2.0,OA=-4,AB=2,spotAi=10,spotBi=270,spotFi=90] }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this removes the rays. Is there a way to remove the image arrow on the right? I manage to remove the A' and B' with `nameAi=,  nameBi=` , but not the arrow itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do somenthing similar to this but when I used `rayColor=white` the rays are still there causing a bad output. The documentation says that `drawing=false` is only for mirrors. But I found something useful.

```tex
\lens[onlyrays=true,linestyle=none,rayColor=white]
```

This erases every line, so you need to put again the desired lines (AB, A'B', etc)

For the following output I used:

```tex
    \resetOpticOptions
    \begin{pspicture*}(-5,-3.5)(5,3.5)
        \rput(0,0){
            \lens[
                lensType=CVG,yBottom=-3.5,yTop=3.5,onlyrays=true,lensHeight=6.5,spotFi=315,lensWidth=0.05,lensColor=black,rayColor=white,
                focus=2.0,OA=-4,AB=2,spotAi=10,spotBi=270,spotFi=90,linestyle=none
            ]
        }
        \psline[linestyle=solid,linecolor=black](A)(B)
        \psline[linestyle=solid,linecolor=black](A')(B')
        \psline[linestyle=solid,linecolor=black]{<->}(0,-3.5)(0,3.5)% AB = 3
        \psline[linestyle=solid,linecolor=black](-5,0)(5,0)
    \end{pspicture*}
```

[image]